# Navbar overflows scrollbars

Tags: css, responsive-design, scrollbar, overflow, navbar

I've been struggling with this problem for a few days now. Navigation bar on [my page](http://kvarkyup.tk/) hides browser scrollbars. This happens in Chrome (both desktop and mobile) and Firefox - I didn't chceck other browsers yet but I suppose the result will be the same.
I tried like every single solution I found on Google and Stack Overflow but none of them fully worked. The navbar either kept covering the scrollbars or it wasn't clickable because it was under the rest of the page.
Can somebody browse my CSS and help me with this problem? Thanks a lot!
P.S.: I use no CSS framework. I downloaded the template from [here](https://www.myresponsee.com/responsive-website-templates/#stickyfooter) and sligtly modified it.